# discord.py music bot AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py, bots

hey guys im a beginner programmer. I’m currently working on a music bot

I am able too make the boat join the voice channel leave etc, just coming down to playing the music everything seems to work okay but then it spits me out this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'` after a bit of research i'm still quite stuck and managed to solve some errors before hand but this error has had me researching etc for a while, if anyone has a bit more information would be great thank you.

i tried researching seeing if anyone has solved this problem before

```
@bot.command(name='playy', help='This command pauses the song')
async def playyt(ctx, url):
    song_there = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        em8 = discord.Embed(title = "Music Is Currently Playing", description = 'Please wait for the current playing music to end or use %leave <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>.\nMusic provided by {ctx.author.mention} <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>',color = ctx.author.color)
        await ctx.send(embed = em8)
        return

    voiceChannel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels)
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    em6 = discord.Embed(title = "Downloading Youtube Music", description = f'{url}\n\nPlease wait for paimon to setup the music you provide.\nMusic provided by {ctx.author.mention} <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>',color = ctx.author.color)
    await ctx.send(embed = em6, delete_after = 2)
    await ctx.message.delete()

    ydl_opts = {
        'format': 'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors': [{
            'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
            'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
            'preferredquality': '196',
        }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file, "song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
    em1 = discord.Embed(title = "Now Listening Youtube Music", description = f'{url}\n\nPlease use %leave first to change music.\nMusic provided by {ctx.author.mention} <:_Paimon6:827074349450133524>',color = ctx.author.color)

    videoID = url.split("watch?v=")[1].split("&")[0]

    em1.set_thumbnail(url = f'https://img.youtube.com/vi/{videoID}/default.jpg'.format(videoID = videoID))
    await ctx.send(embed = em1)
```

Comment: First of all, it is very inconvenient to work with screenshots of codes. Please paste the relevant code directly into your posts.

About your error: as the error message `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'play'` already suggests, your variable `voice` is of type `None` and therefore has no `play()`.
Since the part where `voice` is initialized is not visible in the screenshots, I can't tell why it is None.

Comment: @TimbowSix Sorry for my rookie error with the screenshots. I updated with the code hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`await voiceChannel.connect()` should return a `VoiceClient` that has the `play` method.
Try:

```
voice = await voiceChannel.connect()
```

instead of your

```
await voiceChannel.connect()
voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
```

check [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=connect#discord.VoiceClient) for further information.

Comment: Thank you that worked for me, I will have a read through the documentation for a better understanding.